# Adding correction column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe I read from a csv file with `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")`:

```
date,location,value1,value2
2020-01-01,place1,1,2
2020-01-02,place2,5,8
2020-01-03,place2,2,9
```

I also have a dataframe with corrections `df_corr = pd.read_csv("corrections .csv")`

```
date,location,value
2020-01-02,place2,-1
2020-01-03,place2,2
```

How do I apply these corrections where date and location match to get the following?

```
date,location,value1,value2
2020-01-01,place1,1,2
2020-01-02,place2,4,8
2020-01-03,place2,4,9
```

EDIT:
I got two good answers and decided to go with `set_index()`. Here is how I did it 'non-destructively'.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df_corr = pd.read_csv("corr.csv")

idx = ['date', 'location']

df_corrected = df.set_index(idx).add(
    df_corr.set_index(idx).rename(
        columns={"value": "value1"}), fill_value=0
    ).astype(int).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set  date and location as index in both dataframes, add the two and fillna

```
df.set_index(['date','location'], inplace=True)
df1.set_index(['date','location'], inplace=True)
df['value1']=(df['value1']+df1['value']).fillna(df['value1'])
```

Comment: This is will fail because you are missing location

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to join the two DataFrames on the `date` and `location` columns. After that its a simple matter of applying the correction by adding the `value1` and `value` columns (and finally dropping the column containing the corrections).

```py
# Join on the date and location columns.
df_corrected = pd.merge(df, df_corr, on=['date', 'location'], how='left')

# Apply the correction by adding the columns.
df_corrected.value1 = df_corrected.value1 + df_corrected.value

# Drop the correction column.
df_corrected.drop(columns='value', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I had to specify merge(how='outer'), otherwise rows were dropped and I had to add `df_corrected.value1 = df_corrected.value1.fillna(0).astype(int)`. Otherwise a good tip.

Comment: I see. So the corrections are a subset of the things being corrected. In that case I think what you actually want to do is a `left` join, not outer. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that probably makes more sense. In my case I didn’t have any correction values for non-existing entries, so I didn’t notice.